# Remove characters from NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *myString = @"A B C D E F G";
```

I want to remove the spaces, so the new string would be "ABCDEFG".

Answer (score 283):

You could use:

```
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [myString 
   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Please can you format code snippets in a monospaced font for legibility. At present distinguishing the first string is a little tricky

Comment: Note that “occurrences” is spelled with two r's.

Comment: plus 1 in hope of reaching 256. smh

Comment: This ONLY works if the 'spaces' are well behaved ASCII value=32 (%20) characters. To remove ALL possible white-space chars use Jim Dovey's solution below.

Answer (score 79):

If you want to support more than one space at a time, or support any whitespace, you can do this:

```
NSString* noSpaces =
    [[myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
                           componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: It is more useful for general usage.

Comment: i like it! I want to remove all special char in a phone number and keep only digits.

Comment: much easier: yourString = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

Comment: Trimming only removes matching characters when they occur at the beginning and end of the string, so ` A B C D E F ` would become `A B C D E F`.

Answer (score 11):

Taken from [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:
```

Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are replaced by another given string.

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Parameters

target

```
The string to replace.
```

replacement

```
The string with which to replace target.
```

Return Value

A new string in which all occurrences of target in the receiver are replaced by replacement.

Answer (score 10):

All above will works fine. But the right method is this:

```
yourString = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

It will work like a TRIM method. It will remove all front and back spaces.

Thanks

Comment: Nope, it only removes spaces from the start and end of the string, not spaces in between other characters.

Comment: @JimDovey I already mention this thing in my comment.  #It will work like a TRIM method. It will remove all front and back spaces.#

Comment: @MiteshKhatri You do, but it still doesn't solve the original problem, which is to remove all whitespace from within the middle of the string, not just leading & trailing whitespace.

Comment: @JimDovey for remove all spaces use below code:
MyStr = [MyStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

Comment: That'll still only remove ASCII space characters; things like zero-width spaces, Unicode non-breaking spaces, newlines, form feeds, tabs, vertical tabs, and so on will still remain in the string. Hence the existence of `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]` and `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]`.

Answer (score 6):

if the string is **mutable**, then you can transform it in place using this form:

```
[string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                        withString:@""
                           options:0
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

this is also useful if you would like the result to be a mutable instance of an input string:

```
NSMutableString * string = [concreteString mutableCopy];
[string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                        withString:@""
                           options:0
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
- (NSString *)stripRemoveSpaceFrom:(NSString *)str {
    while ([str rangeOfString:@"  "].location != NSNotFound) {
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
    return str;
}
```

Hope this will help you out.