# iOS - Weird character breaking my drawInRect: method

Tags: ios

I am drawing text to a UIView using drawInRect:. I obtain the text to draw from a server side script. In at least one case, the character \U00a0 is found in the string that I am receiving from the server and that single character is breaking the drawInRect: method. Meaning, it will draw all of the text up until that character, but will not draw any text past that character. Does anyone have any idea what that character is? I did some Googling and learned that the character is the non-breaking space in unicode, although when I NSLog the string, the character shows up as a middle dot. Below is an example of the string that I get back from the server. It is riddled with \n and \t (another thing I am trying to clean up), but you can see the \U00a0 about half way through.

`\n\tDescription
\n
\n\t\U00a0
\n
\n\t`

Any help would be appreciated. Bonus points if you can figure out a way for me to remove it from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answers in this related question:

[Remove characters from NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925780/remove-character-from-nsstring-in-iphone-programming)

I'm thinking you should be able to put your string into a `NSMutableString` object and then remove the offending characters by using NSMutableString's [`replaceOccurencesOfString: withString: options: range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:) method and just `@"\U00A0"` as the string to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been an odd byproduct of using GTMNSString+HTML.h to unescape HTML characters. The character originally was in fact a non-breaking HTML space,  , and got converted to \u00a0 in the process of using gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML. As long as I strip the string of   before running gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML, everything appears to be fine.