# User input validation using regex in Cocoa for osx

Tags: objective-c, regex, macos, cocoa, validation

just faced the problem of inability to write a good regex that would satisfy my needs. I've never used regex before, so that wasn't a big surprise for me.

Here are the good input examples that I'm trying to validate:

- 01
- 00:01
- 01:02:03
- 01:02:03:04 - max 3 colons possible
- 123,456,789 - max two commas possible
- 40000035
- 1:2:06

here are the bad ones:

- ,3234
- 134,2343,333
- 000:01:00
- :01:03:00
- :01
- 01:

First I tried to write one that would cover at least all the colon cases and here is what I have:

```
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = -1;

NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([([0-9]{1,2}):]{1,3})([0-9]{1,2})"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                       error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}

numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:stringToValidate
                                         options:0
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToValidate length])];
```

I'm also curious if NSRegularExpression has any methods to extract the validated substrings in a some sort of an array?!

For example:

12:23:63 --- would be validated and the array would contain [12,23,63]

234 --- would be validated and the array would contain [234]

123,235,653 --- would be validated and the array would contain [123235653]

basically colon separated input would be as separate values and everything else would be as one value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, you I suggest you do one for each case for validation.

## Validation

#### Colons:

```
^\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2}){0,2}(?::\d{2})?$
```

#### Commas:

```
^\d{3}(?:,\d{3}){0,2}$
```

#### Just the number:

```
^\d+$
```

Then assuming you pass validation of each case, use something else for data extraction.

## Data Extraction

#### Colons

- [Simply do a string split on the colons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c)

#### Commas:

- [Remove all occurences of `,` in the string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925780/remove-characters-from-nsstring-in-iphone-programming)

#### Just the number:

- Well, you have what you need here, so no need to make any changes.

Comment: Hi! thank you so much! It looks like it's working ;) Do you know by any chance if there is a method in NSRegularExpression that will allow me to get these matched substrings? For example: in 01:34:23 the ones would be 01 34 and 23 ?

Comment: You would have to modify the regular expression with capture groups in the correct locations. I wouldn't recommend the "One ring to rule them all" solution if you do this. If you add this specification to your question, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you! just edited the question a bit! I also added one more valid/invalid case, but I guess it can be fixed by adding {1,2} after \d ?!