# NSNumberFormatter removing spaces before currency

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I am using `NSNumberFormatter` to format my numbers to strings.
I have a device with Hebrew (israel) region format (settings->General->International->Region Format).
When I try to format the number 100 for instance I get 100 $.
My goal is to remove the space before the currency sign and get just 100$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up changing positiveSuffix and negativeSuffix properties
by removing the spaces from them

because my NSNumberFormatter is static in my application I set them to nil at the end of each use

```
static NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter;
if (!currencyFormatter) {
     currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
     [currencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:@""];
}

// remove spaces at the suffix
currencyFormatter.positiveSuffix = [currencyFormatter.positiveSuffix stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

currencyFormatter.negativeSuffix = [currencyFormatter.negativeSuffix stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


// get the return number
NSString* retNum = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:val];

// this code is for the next time using currencyFormatter
currencyFormatter.positiveSuffix = nil;
currencyFormatter.negativeSuffix = nil;

return retNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just removing all spaces from the string before running it through NSNumberFormatter? (as answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925780/remove-characters-from-nsstring-in-iphone-programming))

```
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [myString 
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: In some formats spaces are used to separate digits instead of commas.
I am looking for a safer way

Comment: Perhaps you could replace ` $` with `$`? But I guess there may also be a clause which breaks this.